# Retorno de null al crear un modelo Java OpenNLP

Tags: java, jnlp

Buenas estoy intentando crear un modelo con OpenNLP
Me surge el problema de que al intentar crear el modelo con el archivo me retorna null.

La parte del codigo en si es:

```
           model = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/en-pos-maxent.bin");
           final POSModel posModel = new POSModel(model);**
```

model sale null y desde ahi ya falla.

¿Alguien sabe el porque?
El archivo en-pos-maxent.bin esta en la ruta de la ejecucion del programa.

Comment: Bueno, esto es simplemente que no encuentra tu archivo **en-pos-maxent.bin** para abrirlo. Una de las contras de Java es hay 835 maneras diferentes de abrir un archivo, cada una con sutiles diferencias. Depende si estás ejecutando tu código dentro de un jar, como archivos en el filesystem, dentro del IDE, etc.
Agrega un poco más de contexto para ver si te podemos ayudar.

Comment: Buenas Alex, 

Gracias por tu respuesta. 

La verdad es que es cierto que no encuentra el archivo pero no se en que puede fallar. 

Tengo una carpeta que se llama src en la que estan los .java del programa que estoy desarrollando. En esa misma carpeta he incuido el archivo ("en-pos-maxent.bin"). He probado tambien ha meter la ruta completa, pero me sigue fallando, Es decir he emtido C:/User/Documents...../en-pos-maxent.bin") Se te ocurre en que puedo estar fallando? El IDE es InteIiJ 
El archivo es para crear un modelo con la libreia jar de apache opennlp.

Answer (score 0):

Según las rutas, estas pueden ser absolutas, relativas o canónicas.

La ruta absoluta es la que nace desde la letra de unidad (C:/bla bla bla/... D:/bla bla bla)

Las rutas relativas son las que nacen a partir de un directorio base. En este caso, también es posible especificar este tipo de ruta en los códigos, partiendo desde la raiz del proyecto. Por lo que es normal usar la carpeta src, y dentro de esa carpeta las carpetas correspondientes a nuestros paquetes. Por ejemplo: "src/paqueteA/archivo.bin"

LAs rutas canónicas pueden partir desde la misma carpeta desde donde está el archivo de la clase que lo llama. Es decir, la misma carpeta que el archivo .java en el que se llama a nuestro fichero .bin. En cuyo caso. En cuyo caso, si está en la misma carpeta, basta con el nombre del archivo. Si hay que subir algún nivel, en Windows es ..\, si hay que bajar un nivel, habría que especificar la carpeta.
Por ejemplo, en la misma carpeta donde tienes tu archivo .java tienes un subdirectorio llamado carpeta, así pues la ruta podría ser "carpeta/archivo.extension".

Así pues, dependiendo de donde tengas tu archivo .bin y con respecto a donde vayas a ejecutar tu programa, sea mejor tener tus archivos en unos sitios que en otros, y sea mejor usar un tipo de ruta u otra.

Comment: Hola Kritik gracias por responder. 

Te comento, tengo los archivos .java en la carpeta src, junto a ellos he metido el archivo en concreto en-pos-maxent.bin en la misma carpeta, es por ello que pongo asi la ruta.

Tambien he intentado poner la ruta absoluta De forma que quedaria como:
"C:/Users/Rikar/Documents...../src/en-pos-maxent.bin"   

Pero me sigue devolviendo null, creo que el problema es correcto y no coge la ruta, pero no entiendo en que puede fallar-

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Echale un vistazo al manual de la API:https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.9.2/manual/opennlp.html#tools.postagger.tagging. ahí lo hacen con otra clase

Comment: Muchas Gracias Jesus. 

Me he leido el manual que has pasado y cambiando la linea que me daba error por: 
try (InputStream modelIn = new FileInputStream("en-pos-maxent.bin"){
  POSModel model = new POSModel(modelIn);

Funciona. La verdad es que todo lo que habia mirado lo estaban haciendo como yo habia puesto y por eso pensaba que era otra cosa. 
La solución era cambiarlo y ralizarlo como he puesto arriba (por si alguien lee esto y le sucede lo mismo)

Comment: Como comentario personal, no se por qué hay tantos modelos en inglés, y con todas las personas del mundo que hablan en español no existen más modelos en español, o corpus. Yo sólo he encontrado 1 del año catapun, y ni siquiera es demasiado bueno.